# What is used array variables in AgensGraph ver1.3 release?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, agens-graph

I used in AgensGraph release 1.3
but I don't used where clause in operator.

e.g:

```
eya=# CREATE (a:person {name:['ljh','jhlee'], age:102});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)

CREATE TABLE t_name (
     name text,
     age int
);

CREATE TABLE
insert into t_name values ('ljh', '102');
INSERT 0 1
eya=# insert into t_name values ('khan', '101');
INSERT 0 1

eya=# SELECT *
FROM   t_name
WHERE  name IN (MATCH (a:person) WHERE a.age = 102 RETURN a.name);
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MATCH" LINE 3: WHERE  name IN (MATCH
>   (a:person) WHERE a.age = 102 RETURN a....

Answer (score 0):

You should regexp in AgensGraph ver 1.3 release.
because, 1.3 version auto, and explicit type casting not operated.
so. you query executed below

SELECT * FROM t_name WHERE name IN (SELECT regexp_replace(unnest(string_to_array(t1.name::text, ',')),'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', 'g')
FROM (MATCH (a:person) WHERE a.age = 102 RETURN a.name) t1);

name | age
------+-----
 ljh  | 102